# Skip XML validation of one tag within choice tag

Tags: xml, validation, schema

I'm trying to specify a schema that roughly starts out like this:

```xml
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="baz" />
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="foo" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="bar" minOccurs="1"/>
                </xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="bam" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

So pretty simple, we've got a sequence with some required elements before and after a `<choice>` element. I want to specify the following behavior, however when validating an instance of this schema:

- If the choice is a `<foo>` element, the validator should validate the children of `<foo>` according to foo's schema
- If the choice is a `<bar>` element, the validator should **ignore** the children of `<bar>` and continue validating the rest of the sequence (so in this example, after detecting there was a `<bar>` element, it would just check to see there is a `<bam>` element next in the sequence and ignore everything between `<bar>` and `</bar>`)
- Obviously the validator should enforce the `<choice>` tag - there can be either a `<foo>` or a `<bar>` at this location, but not both

The reason for this is that I'm attempting to validate an XML file from within my own custom application. I have access to an .xsd file for `<foo>`, but I don't have access to an .xsd for `<bar>`, so I'm trying to validate everything I can validate and ignore what I can't.

Is there something I can add to the schema that tells the validator to honor the `<choice>` tag, but then only care about validating one of the chosen elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give `bar` a type of `xs:anyType`, then it's allowed to have any content - effectively the contents are not validated.